# Set VS Code Extension Configuration Values During Installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a vs code extension with two configuration values.

```
"configuration": [
            {
                "title": "Test",
                "properties": {
                    "conf.test.string2": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Installation Directory",
                        "scope": "window"
                    },
                    "conf.test.string1": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Directory",
                        "scope": "resource"
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am installing the extension using a custom installer which will run `code <extension-name.vsix>` for installing. How can I set the default values for these configurations during the installation? The values are derived during the installation by the custom installer.

Is there a way to pass the values in the commandline or any other way during the installation?

Comment: Default values are in your `package.json` file (please add `default` property to your settings), so I wonder why you want to set it another time.

Comment: @LexLi I am using a custom installer code to install the extension. So the default values will be known only at the run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the configuration value to Settings.json in `%APPDATA%/Code/User/settings.json`